# Visual basic 6 issue with combobox

Tags: combobox, vb6

I have created a forum in vb6 and made connection with a database in access,everything went perfect.
my problem is in my form there is 2 combobox one to select Number and other to get me other numbers (watch the video to understand )
anyway the first combo is working and the second combo is working too but after selecting different number from the first combo i don't get anything in the second combo.anyway i know i just miss something in the code something very stupid 
i have uploaded a video so you can see my problem, thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
liaison
Do Until rspatient.EOF
   Me.npa.AddItem rspatient.Fields(0)
   rspatient.MoveNext
   Loop
End Sub

Private Sub npa_Click()
rspatient.MoveFirst
Dim cr As String
cr = "npation ='" & npa & "'"
rspatient.Find cr
nom = rspatient.Fields(1)
prenom = rspatient.Fields(3)
rshospita.MoveFirst
nh.Clear
While rshospita.EOF = False
   If UCase(rshospita.Fields(14)) = UCase(npa) Then
         nh.AddItem rshospita.Fields(0)
         End If
         rshospita.MoveNext
         Wend

End Sub
```

video for more detail :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tidm18_tvp0

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible reason for your problem is that you don't have any hospital records associated with your second patient.  Check that first.

However, your code is also a bit convoluted.  A simpler way to do what you want is to use Filter instead of Find.  Filter restricts your recordset to only those records which match the filter, so you can simply iterate the filtered recordset the same way you do the whole one (rspatient).  Something like this:

```
Private Sub npa_Click()
    With rshospita
        .Filter = ".Fields(14) = '" & npa & "'"
        .MoveFirst
        nh.Clear
        Do Unitl .EOF
            nh.AddItem .Fields(0)
       .MoveNext
    End With
End Sub
```